# MMAP variables behave strangely when addressed from struct

Tags: c++

Why do my `mmap` variables behave strangely when I call them from `struct`?

### Minimal Failure Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>        // provides usleep
#include <sys/mman.h>      // provides mmap
#include <sys/wait.h>      // provides wait

struct val_addresses {
    int ** ABORTaddr;
    int ** VARaddr;
    } val_ptr;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // mmap variables
    auto *VAR = static_cast <int *> (mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
    auto *ABORT = static_cast <int *> (mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
    val_ptr.VARaddr = &VAR;
    val_ptr.ABORTaddr = &VAR;
    *VAR = 0;
    *ABORT = 0;

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0) {
        // Parent
        while (*(int *)*(int *)val_ptr.ABORTaddr == 0) {
            std::cout << *(int *)*(int *)val_ptr.VARaddr << std::endl;
            usleep(500000);
        }
        wait(0);

    } else {
        // Child
        usleep(1000000);
        std::cout << "set to 1" << std::endl;
        *(int *)*(int *)val_ptr.VARaddr = 1;
        usleep(1000000);
        std::cout << "set to 2" << std::endl;
        *(int *)*(int *)val_ptr.VARaddr = 2;
        usleep(1000000);
        std::cout << "set to quit" << std::endl;
        *(int *)*(int *)val_ptr.VARaddr = 0;
        usleep(1000000);
        *(int *)*(int *)val_ptr.ABORTaddr = 1;
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The preceding code was compiled on a Raspberry Pi 3 with `g++` The observed behavior is that the child dutifully reports the into the terminal each step.  Meanwhile, the parent only reports before the `VAR` changes the first time.

```
$ ./test 
0
0
0
set to 1
set to 2
set to quit
```

### Minimal Working Example

The code works as I would expect when I replace every instance of `*(int *)*(int *)val_ptr.VARaddr` with `*VAR`.  This is the standard way of accessing the variable without using a `struct`.  However, this is a portion of a much larger project, and having the memory mapped variables stored with `struct` is necessary.

Comment: `(int *)val_ptr.ABORTaddr` Why do you cast it? It already is a `int**`, why cast it to `int*`? Remove _all_ the casts and just `**val_ptr.VARaddr`. `This is the standard way of accessing the variable without using a struct` no, it makes no sense. Using a structure doesn't mean you have to use double `**`. `the memory mapped variables stored with struct` But you are storing _pointers to pointers_ of memory mapped region.

Comment: Is this true even if I am not storing ``VAR`` in the ``struct``, rather I am storing the address to find ``VAR`` there?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @KamilCuk, I was able to reduce the casting to a correct level.  I'm not sure why I had everything double cast, but I remember having troubles in earlier iterations with accessing the value rather than the address.

### Corrections should look like:

1. Reduce the unary in the struct by one

> ```
> struct val_addresses {
>     int * ABORTaddr;
>     int * VARaddr;
>     } val_ptr;
> ```

2. The `mmap` call should be directly to the struct address (drop the `static_cast`)

> ```
> val_ptr.VARaddr = (int *)(mmap(NULL, sizeof(int),
> PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
> ```

3. Omit Address Assignment

> e.g.
>
> ```
> val_ptr.VARaddr = &VAR;
> ```
>
> becomes:

4. Assign values to addresses in the `struct` directly

> e.g.
>
> ```
> *VAR = 0;
> ```
>
> becomes:
>
> ```
> *val_ptr.VARaddr = 0;
> ```

5. Access and assign values with single pointer

> e.g.
>
> ```
> *(int *)*(int *)val_ptr.VARaddr
> ```
>
> becomes:
>
> ```
> *val_ptr.VARaddr
> ```

## The result of the corrections:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>        // provides usleep
#include <sys/mman.h>      // provides mmap
#include <sys/wait.h>      // provides wait

struct val_addresses {
    int * ABORTaddr;
    int * VARaddr;
    } val_ptr;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // mmap variables
    val_ptr.VARaddr = (int *)(mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
    val_ptr.ABORTaddr = (int *)(mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
    *val_ptr.VARaddr = 0;
    *val_ptr.ABORTaddr = 0;

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0) {
        // Parent
        while (*val_ptr.ABORTaddr == 0) {
            std::cout << *val_ptr.VARaddr << std::endl;
            usleep(500000);
        }
        wait(0);

    } else {
        // Child
        usleep(1000000);
        std::cout << "set to 1" << std::endl;
        *val_ptr.VARaddr = 1;
        usleep(1000000);
        std::cout << "set to 2" << std::endl;
        *val_ptr.VARaddr = 2;
        usleep(1000000);
        std::cout << "set to quit" << std::endl;
        *val_ptr.VARaddr = 0;
        usleep(1000000);
        *val_ptr.ABORTaddr = 1;
        
    }

    return 0;
```